# Percentile aggregate for SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, aggregate-functions, percentile

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2. I need to compute a percentile value per group, something like:

```
SELECT id,
       PCTL(0.9, x) -- for the 90th percentile
FROM my_table
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id
```

For example, given this DDL ([fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a3661/1)) ---

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (id INT, x REAL);

INSERT INTO my_table
VALUES (7, 0.164595), (5, 0.671311), (7, 0.0118385), (6, 0.704592), (3, 0.633521), (3, 0.337268), (0, 0.54739), (6, 0.312282), (0, 0.220618), (7, 0.214973), (6, 0.410768), (7, 0.151572), (7, 0.0639506), (5, 0.339075), (1, 0.284094), (2, 0.126722), (2, 0.870079), (3, 0.369366), (1, 0.6687), (5, 0.199456), (5, 0.0296715), (1, 0.330339), (9, 0.0000459612), (5, 0.391947), (3, 0.753965), (8, 0.334207), (7, 0.583357), (3, 0.326951), (4, 0.207057), (2, 0.258463), (2, 0.0532811), (1, 0.751584), (7, 0.592624), (7, 0.673506), (5, 0.44764), (6, 0.733737), (5, 0.141215), (7, 0.222452), (3, 0.597019), (1, 0.293901), (4, 0.516213), (7, 0.498336), (6, 0.410461), (2, 0.32211), (1, 0.466735), (5, 0.720456), (8, 0.000428383), (3, 0.46085), (0, 0.402963), (7, 0.677002), (0, 0.400122), (1, 0.762357), (9, 0.158455), (7, 0.359723), (4, 0.225914), (7, 0.795345), (6, 0.902261), (2, 0.69533), (8, 0.593605), (6, 0.266233), (0, 0.917188), (9, 0.96353), (2, 0.577035), (8, 0.945236), (3, 0.257776), (4, 0.560569), (0, 0.838326), (2, 0.660338), (2, 0.537372), (8, 0.33806), (0, 0.545107), (1, 0.616673), (5, 0.30411), (0, 0.434737), (2, 0.588249), (9, 0.991362), (8, 0.772253), (6, 0.705396), (5, 0.323255), (8, 0.830319), (3, 0.679546), (4, 0.399748), (4, 0.440115), (6, 0.938154), (8, 0.333143), (9, 0.923541), (7, 0.19552), (4, 0.869822), (7, 0.620006), (4, 0.833529), (4, 0.297515), (4, 0.19906), (5, 0.540905), (9, 0.33313), (5, 0.200515), (5, 0.900481), (6, 0.02665), (3, 0.495421), (0, 0.96582), (9, 0.847218);
```

--- I want approximately (within variation of [common percentile methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile)) the following:

```
id  x
----------
0   0.9658
1   0.7624
2   0.6953
3   0.6795
4   0.8335
5   0.7205
6   0.9023
7   0.677
8   0.9452
9   0.9914
```

The actual input set has about two million rows, and each actual `id` group has a few dozen to a few hundred (or possibly more) rows.

I've explored SO and other sites for solutions, but it seems like the couple dozen or so pages I checked have solutions that are only applicable to computing a percentile over an entire row set rather than each group/partition of a row set. (I'm relatively inexperienced with SQL, so I might have overlooked something.)

I've also looked at the docs for [the ranking functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798(v=sql.105).aspx), but I haven't been able to glue together a query that would work.

I'd like to use [PERCENTILE_DISC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231327(v=sql.110).aspx) or [PERCENTILE_CONT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231473(v=sql.110).aspx), but I'm stuck with 2008 R2 for now.

Comment: You have tagged your question with SQL Server 2008R2 version, PERCENTILE_DISC and PERCENTILE_CONT were introduced in sql server 2012, Your only option is to use `NTILE(90) OVER (PARTITION BY SomeColumn)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I like to do these calculations directly, using `row_number()`/`rank()` and window functions.  The built-in functions are useful, but they don't actually save that much effort:

```
SELECT id,
       MIN(CASE WHEN seqnum >= 0.9 * cnt THEN x END) as percentile_90
FROM (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by x) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by id) as cnt
      from my_table t
     ) t
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id;
```

This takes the first value that is at the 90th percentile or greater.  There are variations on this that can do the continuous version (take the largest value less than or equal to and the smallest one bigger than and interpolate).

Comment: For the median case where we have an even number of observations, where we ideally compute the average of the two nearest points you could alter you select line using the AVG instead of MIN like so:
AVG(CASE WHEN seqnum IN ( CEILING(0.5 * cnt) , FLOOR(0.5 * cnt +1))  THEN x END) as percentile_50