# Calculating the Percentile value in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server, percentile

I want to calculating the Percentile value in sql server 2008.
This script work in sqlserver 2012 but 2008.
Is there percentile_cont equivalent in sqlserver 2008?

```
select DISTINCT col_1,col_2
,PERCENTILE_CONT(0.25) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col_3) OVER (PARTITION BY col_1,col_2) AS P25
,PERCENTILE_CONT(0.50) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col_3) OVER (PARTITION BY col_1,col_2) AS P50
,PERCENTILE_CONT(0.75) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col_3) OVER (PARTITION BY col_1,col_2) AS P75
from table
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Percentile aggregate for SQL Server 2008 R2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27850364/percentile-aggregate-for-sql-server-2008-r2)

Comment: Thanks. I tried the sql. But I found the calculating result is different from using PERVENTILE_CONT.